# How to use ssh to schedule an 'at' job or a 'cron job' on a linux server from a python program on Windows client

Tags: python, linux, cron, at-utility

I am attempting to schedule a job to run on a linux server from a python app on Windows 10 by using os.system(). The following code executes but fails to schedule the job.

```
os.system('ssh myadmin@mnop.com "at 09:00 {}".format("iostat > /home/myadmin/t.txt")')
os.system('ssh myadmin@mnop.com  "crontab 0 9 9 1 * /home/myadmin.msg.sh"')
```

My objective is to schedule a one time execution. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The sole argument to `at` is the time; it then reads the commands from standard input. Similarly, `crontab` reads the cron schedule from standard input, not as parameters to the command.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['ssh', 'myadmin@mnop.com', 'at 09:00'],
    text=True, check=True,
    input="iostat > /home/myadmin/t.txt\n")
subprocess.run(['ssh', 'myadmin@mnop.com', 'crontab'],
    text=True, check=True,
    input='0 9 9 1 * /home/myadmin/msg.sh\n')
```

Notice that the latter will replace any existing `crontab` for the user. I fixed the typo you pointed out in a comment.

Notice also how we switch to `subprocess.run` instead of `os.system`, as recommended in the documentation for the latter. I refactored to avoid having to use `shell=True`; perhaps see also [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: The 'at' solution that you provided works fine. Thank you, tripleee.  When executing the 'crontab' solution, I get the following error:  CalledProcessError: Command '['ssh', 'myadmin@mnop.com', 'crontab']' returned non-zero exit status 1.  (I made a typo on the input. Should be, input='0 9 9 1 * /home/myadmin/msg.sh'

Comment: Then I guess it gives you an error message telling you what's wrong? You can substantially simplify your troubleshooting by taking out the Python and SSH parts. Try adding a dash, like `crontab -`

Comment: I tested on both Linux and macOS and neither of them require a dash with `crontab`. If you are installing a crontab for `root` your syntax is wrong (it requires a fifth field before the command to identify which user to run the job as).

Comment: If this is all the code you are running, you really don't need Python here. Using `format` to merge two static strings is decidedly odd but perhaps this is a reduced example from more complex code where these complications make sense.

Comment: Both solutions that you provided are now working. The crontab error, "non-zero exit status 1" was resolved by adding a '\n' at the end of the input='0 9 9 1 * /home/myadmin/msg.sh\n'  Thanks for your clear instructions.